# Bot Builder 3.13.0 update broke FormDialog

Tags: botframework

I updated my Bot.Builder and Bot.Connector from 3.12.2.4 to 3.13.0 - suddenly my Form would not work: it would show the enum options list but clicking on an item does nothing (it normally posts back a message).

I rolled back to 3.12.2 and my Form worked again.

Here is my [Solution](https://github.com/oyen/OyenSolution/commits/master). The fist 2 commits on Feb1-2018 are:

1. Added Form + updated all NuGet except Bot. This commit has a working Form.
2. Updated Bot to 13.3.0 - and then the Form stops working.

Comment: For your 1st question, please add your code / details of implementation

Comment: @NicolasR https://github.com/oyen/OyenSolution/commits/master I did 2 commits today. First was to update all nuget (except Bot) and add a Form. That commit will work and run. The latest commit as of now is simply updating Bot nuget to 13.3.0 and that breaks my Form.

Comment: can you please separate this out into 2 questions, form flow and migration

Comment: @JasonSowers I did as you said and here's the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48573221/bot-migrate-logged-in-as-creator-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug that was introduced in 3.13.0.  The recommended fallback is to roll back to 3.12.2.4 until the fix can be deployed.  I do not have an ETA currently but should be in the next couple of days from this answer, if not sooner.