# Bot Migrate logged in as creator not working

Tags: botframework

Following [Migrate Your Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-migrate-bot), I get the following error:

[image]

I am logged in with the same credentials as creator of my bot.

Comment: Is your bot a Functions bot or a Web App bot?

Comment: Just received word that a fix for this should be coming out soon.  I'll update here when I know more.

Comment: @BlackSeraph the migrate option on my bot is still not working. Now with a different error: `An error occurred: 404
The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/mybot_XXXXXXX' under resource group 'MyResourceGroup' was not found.`

I tried creating a new bot and the migrate option for that one worked fine.